# Where can I find My Boy! .sav files after running multiple instances?

Tags: emulation, my-boy

I'm using the android emulator My Boy to play Pokemon Fire Red. There is an option to run multiple instances of the same game, and link with yourself. I used this option, but it looks like I saved a state with the emulator, where there was multiple instances.

I would like to transfer the save game to my pc now. For this I have to find the .sav file. Now when I load the rom, and then load the current state, and then save with the in-game save, the .sav file is not saved to the location of the rom (though the game still asks that there is a save file, do I want to owerwrite it)

Does anybody know the location of the savegames under the circumstances I'm in? Or does anybody have an idea where to look for them, or how can I find them?

Comment: Do you have a file manager? And do you remember the default folder? (Where the emulator navigated by default to search for the ROM). This is probably a start.

Comment: I have reinstalled the app for this, it's default directory is the root of the internal storage, but a popup says to place roms on the SD card. Also, the save states made by the emulator can be found at /internalstorage/myboy/save. I did not find the .sav games at these locations.

Comment: I recently got a new phone and transferred my MyBoy! files over. I just dragged my Fire Red .zip from the old phone -> desktop -> new phone, and the game launched with my save intact. From looking at where my ROM is stored, MyBoy! has put the .sav file in the same directory.

Comment: Sadly, my rom is not in a zip, as I have used patches on it, it is a simple .gba file, and usually the save file is next to it, as a .sav file.

Answer (score 1):

After searching through my whole phone, installing android studio, trying to write and android app, failing, installing an app that monitors file operations, and furiously watching the write operations, I managed to solve it.

My app was outdated. I updated it. Now the .sav file of the saved states is in the folder where the state files are.